# Update list after insert item in another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, item, insert-update-listitem

I have to update a list after I insert an item in another list.
For example, I have the main list with a person's details (name, age, address, email etc.). When I insert new person to this list, I want that another list will be inserted automatic a new item with the name and email only.

Comment: You can do this without code using a workflow. Loads of example on the web.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get an informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Using SharePoint Designer. (No code)**

- Open Sharepoint Designer > click on the workflow > new list workflow.
- Click Actions > List Actions > Update List Item.

[image]

- Click this list.
- In the Update List Item dialog box, change the List to your destination list.
- In the Find the List Item section, change the Field list value to the name of the ID field in your second list.
- Click the Workflow Lookup icon, In the Define Workflow Lookup dialog box, change the Field list value to the name of the ID field in the second list.

**Using Event Receiver. (Require code)**

You can create an event receiver on Item added to add to another list, to know how to create an event receiver check [Creating Simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)